# dataframe pandas subset series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas Dataframe `df1` and `df2`. Both has a common column `dealer`. I want to subset `df1` for all those `dealer` who are present in `df2`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
df1[df1['delear'].isin(df2['delear'])]
```

Example:

```
In [24]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'delear':np.arange(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'delear':[2,4]})
df1[df1['delear'].isin(df2['delear'])]
Out[24]:
   delear
2       2
4       4
```

In the situation where you may have duplicate values in df2 'delear' column you can get the unique values by calling `unique`:

```
In [26]:

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'delear':[2,4,4,4,4]})
df2['delear'].unique()
Out[26]:
array([2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

So the code then becomes:

```
df1[df1['delear'].isin(df2['delear'].unique())]
```

Comment: Minor addition `df1[df1['delear'].isin(df2['delear'].unique)]` could be optimal, if there are plenty of repetitive values?

Comment: Yes it would be, but the OP hasn't stated or shown anything to indicate if there could be duplicate values, will update nonetheless

Comment: The above one worked. I didn't have to worry about `unique` as I already deduplicated the data.

Comment: Done.. sorry I am relatively new to this community ! should have done it earlier...

Comment: @SaurabhKumarKarn no worries glad I could help, as a pointer for future questions people usually like to see raw data, your code, full error tracebacks and desired output